# @Input properties with primitive type 'boolean' cannot be @Optional

Tags: gradle, spotbugs

I have the following error message when build with gradle. Do you have idea?
Thanks

```
Property 'showProgress' @Input properties with primitive type 'boolean' cannot be @Optional. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 7.0. See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2.2/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:up_to_date_checks for more details.
```

gradle: 6.2.2
spotbugs: 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `showProgress` to have type `Property<Boolean>` instead of `boolean`